# Trouble proving multiplicativity and triangle inequality of a norm.

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $||*||$ be a norm on a vector space $V$.

$\varphi(v)=\frac{||v||}{1+||v||}$.

I am trying to prove that it's a norm on $V$. I know that I need to prove the 4 properties of the norm. Clearly, $||\varphi||\geq0$. $||\varphi||=0$ iff $\varphi =0$, which is true when $||v||=0$.

But I am having trouble proving that:

1. $||\alpha \varphi || = |\alpha| ||\varphi||$ for $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$
2. $||x+y||\leq ||x|| + ||y||$ in the context of $\varphi$

EDIT (2): For the triangle inequality,

$\varphi(v+w)=\frac{||v+w||}{1+||v+w||}\leq \frac {||v|| + ||w||} {1+ ||v||+||w||} = \frac {||v||} {1+ ||v||+||w||} + \frac {||w||} {1+ ||v||+||w||} \leq \frac {||v||} {1+ ||v||} + \frac {||w||} {1+ ||w||}= \varphi(v) + \varphi(w)$

Also $\varphi(\alpha v)= \frac {|| \alpha v||} {1+ ||\alpha v||} = \frac {|\alpha| ||v||}{1+ |\alpha| ||v||} \neq |\alpha| \varphi(v)$.

Comment: The triangle inequality holds, but the homogeneity doesn't.

Comment: Thank you could you possibly expand on those 2 ideas. Wouldn't $ ||\alpha \varphi|| = \alpha \frac{||v||}{1+||v||}=|\alpha| ||\varphi|| $? How can I even go about expressing the triangle inequality with $\varphi$?

Comment: @DanielFischer, Maybe, instead, for homogeneity to hold, $\varphi(\alpha v) = \alpha \varphi$ which is not the case? If this is the correct way of expressing it, I understand how triangle inequality holds.

Comment: The homogeneity needed for a norm would be $\varphi(\alpha v) = \lvert\alpha\rvert \varphi(v)$. You can directly verify that this doesn't hold unless $\lvert\alpha\rvert \in \{0,1\}$, or you can note that $0 \leqslant \varphi(v) < 1$, and $\varphi(v)$ doesn't vanish identically. For the triangle inequality, use that $g \colon t \mapsto \frac{t}{1+t}$ is (strictly) monotonic on $[0,+\infty)$ and $\varphi(v) = g(\lVert v\rVert)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I finally understand now. Thank you very much! Could you verify that my edit above is correct for both triangle inequality and homogeneity?

Comment: Not quite. In the homogeneity, you forgot the modulus, it must be $\lvert\alpha\rvert$ outside the norm. For the triangle inequality, you made a mistake, you left $\lVert v+w\rVert$ in the denominator for too long. Take $v\neq 0$ and $w = -v$, then the last inequality in that line is invalid. Start  with $\frac{\lVert v+w\rVert}{1 + \lVert v+w\rVert} \leqslant \frac{\lVert v\rVert + \lVert w\rVert}{1 + \lVert v\rVert + \lVert w\rVert}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, corrected my mistakes. I can see why the inequality does not hold. Thank you so much for your help.